# Paypal sandbox post error 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPhOv.png)I have been following a tutorial for a paypal sandbox using react-paypal-express-checkout and have followed it exactly, but when I try to open the paypal window it closes instantly and throws this error.

Photo:[Photo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPhOv.png)

Text:

```
http.js:147 POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles 401 (Unauthorized)

types.js:121 Uncaught Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles failed with 401 error. Correlation id: bfca9a9c3fdfc

{
    "name": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "debug_id": "bfca9a9c3fdfc",
    "message": "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#errors",
    "details": []
}

    at XMLHttpRequest.xhrLoad (http.js:114)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> @ types.js:121
receiveMessage @ index.js:114
messageListener @ index.js:140
setTimeout (async)
dispatchPossiblyUnhandledError @ exceptions.js:16
(anonymous) @ promise.js:122
setTimeout (async)
reject @ promise.js:120
dispatch @ promise.js:179
reject @ promise.js:127
dispatch @ promise.js:179
reject @ promise.js:127
dispatch @ promise.js:186
reject @ promise.js:127
(anonymous) @ promise.js:157
dispatch @ promise.js:184
reject @ promise.js:127
(anonymous) @ promise.js:51
respond @ client.js:147
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> @ types.js:126
receiveMessage @ index.js:114
messageListener @ index.js:140
serialize.js:175 Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles failed with 401 error. Correlation id: bfca9a9c3fdfc

{
    "name": "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
    "debug_id": "bfca9a9c3fdfc",
    "message": "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#errors",
    "details": []
}

    at XMLHttpRequest.xhrLoad (http.js:114)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.<computed> [as postrobot_message_response] (types.js:121)
    at receiveMessage (index.js:114)
    at messageListener (index.js:140)
    at deserializeError (serialize.js:175)
    at serialize.js:212
    at util.js:140
    at eachArray (util.js:102)
    at each (util.js:116)
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)
    at util.js:147
    at eachObject (util.js:109)
    at each (util.js:118)
    at replaceObject (util.js:138)
```

Heres the page for my button and all the tutorial guy changes is the sandbox id which I did:

```
import React from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const onSuccess = (payment) => {
            // Congratulation, it came here means everything's fine!
                    console.log("The payment was succeeded!", payment);
                    // You can bind the "payment" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
        }

        const onCancel = (data) => {
            // User pressed "cancel" or close Paypal's popup!
            console.log('The payment was cancelled!', data);
            // You can bind the "data" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
        }

        const onError = (err) => {
            // The main Paypal's script cannot be loaded or somethings block the loading of that script!
            console.log("Error!", err);
            // Because the Paypal's main script is loaded asynchronously from "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"
            // => sometimes it may take about 0.5 second for everything to get set, or for the button to appear
        }

        let env = 'sandbox'; // you can set here to 'production' for production
        let currency = 'USD'; // or you can set this value from your props or state
        let total = 1; // same as above, this is the total amount (based on currency) to be paid by using Paypal express checkout
        // Document on Paypal's currency code: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

        const client = {
            sandbox:    'ASloDPNYZO9LtigzQd58tcYQHuORCH3TlvPS-LWMdwzIWiEiefonUQE7KmWCE-WkaEaiiJb54RSNcrLE',
            production: 'YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID',
        }
        // In order to get production's app-ID, you will have to send your app to Paypal for approval first
        // For sandbox app-ID (after logging into your developer account, please locate the "REST API apps" section, click "Create App"):
        //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/
        // For production app-ID:
        //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

        // NB. You can also have many Paypal express checkout buttons on page, just pass in the correct amount and they will work!
        return (
            <PaypalExpressBtn env={env} client={client} currency={currency} total={total} onError={onError} onSuccess={onSuccess} onCancel={onCancel} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to hear a follow up on this.  I'm running into the same exact error but only with Live Client ID credentials.  Interestingly this error is just now showing up with code that we've had in production for the last several years.

Answer (score 0):

The react-paypal-express-checkout repository does not reference v1/payment-experience/web-profiles , so I am not sure where your error is actually coming from

The v1/payment-experience/web-profiles API requires a valid `ClientId` and a `Secret` for authentication.

Comment: I put my correct ClientId in, and the guy in the video doesn't need the secret, do you have any suggestions for what I could try?

Comment: Your particular npm or react environment may have pulled in different dependencies or be doing things differently

You'll want to find out what's calling the v1/payment-experience/web-profiles API, and check its configuration